# I want to assign a specific customer's grand total into a variable

Tags: python, django

I want to assign a specific customer's grand total into a variable. I have this Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.price * self.quantity
        return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here i have a field called total. When a customer place a order its show a total. so here i want to take total_by_customer_id after that i want to assign into a variable then i want to substract with the balance.

Here is views:

```
class UserInvoice(View):
    def map_func(self, product):
        cart = self.request.session.get('cart', None)
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id in cart:
            return product.price * cart[product_id]


    def get(self, request, id):
        user_orders = Order.objects.get(pk=id)
        args = {'user_orders':user_orders}
        return render(self.request, 'Home/invoice.html', args)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = request.session.get('customer')
        print(customer)
        index = Order.get_orders_total_by_customer(customer.total)
        
        print(index)
        


        balance = request.session['customer']['coin']
        print(balance)
        if balance >= index.total:
            balance = balance - index.total
            print(balance)
            # Customer.objects.filter(id = request.session['customer']['id']).update(coin=balance)
            customer = Customer.objects.get(id = request.session['customer']['id'])
            customer.coin = balance
            customer.save()
            request.session['customer']['coin'] = balance

            return HttpResponse("Remaining balance: " + str(balance))

        return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

This view is not complete yet because of this problem.

Comment: Am i right if i say you want the sum of orders.total for a specific user id ?

Comment: No bro no @EricMartin i want to get only single orders total Like, i have a system where customer can place order and after placing he will have to have only that order he recelty made, so in that order his total was 500$. Then That customer has balance When he proceed the payment the method will be like this : total - balance = rest amount of his balance. I think you will undertstand Pleaese Help

Comment: Nope, i don't get it. How can you test if an order is paid or not ?